# DataTables pagination css broken in modal datatables

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatable, datatables-1.10

How do I customize the css of datatables?
My pagination seems broken when I am trying to use datatables function in Modal bootstrap.

Also, how can I limit the pagination number that appear in `html` when there are so many data ? 
For example, in the pagination table it have number 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5,...,8
how can I make the pagination into
1, 2 , 3 ,..., 8 ?

The pagination and the row count are just like in a image below.

**My datatables script**

```
 $('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "<?php echo base_url('dashboard/show_karyawan'); ?>",

    "columns": [
       {
          "data": "id",
          render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
              return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
             }
      },
        { "data": "NIP" },
        { "data": "nama" },

    ]
} );
```

**My Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalkaryawan" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"  style="width: 500px;">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="modal-title">
           <center><h4>Silahkan Pilih Karyawan</i></h4></center>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <table id="example" class="table table-striped display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>No</td>
          <td>NIP</td>
          <td>Nama Pegawai</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td>No</td>
          <td>NIP</td>
          <td>Nama Pegawai</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      <center>
          <button type="button" id="savesebab_delete" class="btn btn-primary">Ya</button>
          <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">Tidak</button>
        </center>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried increasing the width of `modal-dialog`?

Comment: oh i didnt know it would work... thanks.

the next problem is how can i limit the pagination number that appear in html when there are so many data ? 
like, in the pagination table it have number 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5,...,8
how can i make the pagination into
1, 2 , 3 ,..., 8 @Ofisora

Comment: It is not possible with just css. You have to embed other plugins as well.  For example,  https://github.com/flaviusmatis/simplePagination.js

Comment: how do i integrate this plugins along with datatables plugins ? @Ofisora

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Comment: sorry about that, i didnt see the notification carefully
but your answer give me a big help, thanks @Ofisora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For limiting the pagination number add the following code before you initialize  the `datatable` inside the script:

`$.fn.DataTable.ext.pager.numbers_length = 5;`

This will make sure that you will have 5 page numbers includeing '`...`'.

I have made a sample demo here: https://codepen.io/Sahero/pen/VzzpvE.

Comment: is this answer not using the js that you gave me before ? @Ofisora

github.com/flaviusmatis/simplePagination.js

Comment: No, this is from the same datatable plugin.